# JQuery UI Autocomplete: how to strip tags from label before inserting into the input field?

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI Autocomplete, I have the set of items returned via ajax with the terms highlighted by the search engine (so the label already contains the html). The problem is that every time I choose an item the value with html tags is inserted into the text box which is of course not nice. I wonder if there is anyway I can strip all tags from the label before inserting into the text box

```
        var cache = {}, lastXhr;
        $('#location_name').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {                 

            var q = request.term;
            if ( q in cache ) {
                response( cache[ q ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( "location_search/", {q: q}, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                $.each(data, function(i, v){
                    data[i].label = v.name + (v.address !== null ? ', ' + v.address : '');
                });

                cache[ q ] = data;

                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {                                        
                    response( cache [q] );
                }
            });
        },      
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#location_id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#selected_location').html(ui.item.label);                        
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ) //  + + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>"
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function:

```
function stripHTML(oldString) {
  return oldString.replace(/<&#91;^>&#93;*>/g, "");
}
```

And add to your code:

```
$('#location_name').change(function(){
    $(this).val(stripHTML($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you Tak, the stripHTML function will come in handy, the issue was not with the $('#selected_location') however, I should have removed that from my code. The issue is with the value of $('#location_name') which is automatically set once the a value of the dropdown is selected

Comment: Ah sorry, I've updated the answer. Hopefully that new function fixes it, otherwise I have another idea. Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks Tak, the idea is great, I can see it should work, unfortunately it doesn't. I think the problem is that it kicks in way before

After some more trials and errors, I found out the solution: (cant seem to figure out how to post nice looking code in the comment). Thanks alot again for your help
`function stripHTML(oldString) {
 return oldString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}

$('#location_name').bind('autocompleteclose', function(){  
     $(this).val(stripHTML($(this).val()));
 });`

Comment: Great, glad you got it fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work you should also pass **item.value**

On select it looks for  **item.value** first and then for  **item.label**

That way you can leave your select: like that

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#selected_location').html(ui.item.label);                        
    }
```